# Почему при записи в локальную память браузера не получается получить правильные данные?

Tags: javascript

Я пытался записать в локальную память некоторые данные и все вроде получилось, но когда попытался проверить соотвествуют ли введенные данные соответствующему ключу, получаю не тот результат, что ожидал.

```
localStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify("Tom12!"));
localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify("QhuR56Rw"));

console.log(localStorage.getItem("login") === "Tom12!"); // Ожидаю true, но получаю false
console.log(localStorage.getItem("token") === "QhuR56Rw"); // Ожидаю true, но получаю false
```

Я ожидал получить `true`, но получаю `false`. Почему?

Comment: Потому что вы записываете результат `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем Вам `JSON.stringify`? Он записывает в локальное хранилище значение в виде `"Tom12!"`, то есть вместе с кавычками. Сравнивать тогда надо с конструкцией `"\"Tom12!\""`:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify("Tom12!") === "\"Tom12!\"");
```

Comment: Даже не знал, что если использовать `stringify`, то записывает сразу с кавычками. Спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: JSON.stringify(), может объекты хранить хочет ...

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, возможно, но вряд ли - здесь же просто логин и пароль. Ума не приложу, зачем использовать JSON.stringify

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли `JSON.parse()`:

```
localStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify("Tom12!"));
localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify("QhuR56Rw"));

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("login")) === "Tom12!"); // true
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")) === "QhuR56Rw"); //true
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ej6asc4k